# Identify who has a missing event

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where events occur in order and there should be a logical progress. However due to a system malfunction, some events are missing and I need to be able to identify them.

I have 2 tables.

1. `NameTbl` contains:

   ```
   eID  FirstNM  LastNM
   ---  -------  ------
   ```
2. `EventTbl` contains:

   ```
   eID  EventLocation  EventNM  EventDate
   ---  -------------  -------  ---------
   ```

The logical order of things should be:

1. Wake Up (`Wake`)
2. Get Dressed (`GetDress`)
3. Drive to Work (`DriveTo`)
4. Start Work (`WorkBegin`)

For whatever reason, some of people are missing a `DriveTo` event, even though I know it happened. What I want to do is identify: All people (`FirstNM` and `LastNM`) in Virginia whose last event is a `WorkBegin` but there is no `DriveTo` preceding it.

NameTbl:

```
eID   FirstNM     LastNM
---   -------     ------
 1     John        Doe
 2     Mary        West
 3     Derek       Smith
```

EventTbl:

```
eID    EventLocation   EventNM            EventDate
---    -------------   ---------     -------------------
 1       Virginia       Wake         2014-06-30 06:00:00
 1       Virginia       GetDress     2014-06-30 06:30:00
 1       Virginia       DriveTo      2014-06-30 06:45:00
 1       Virginia       Work         2014-06-30 07:00:00
 2       Virginia       Wake         2014-06-30 05:00:00
 2       Virginia       GetDress     2014-06-30 06:00:00
            (Missing Event!)
 2       Virginia       Work         2014-06-30 07:00:00
 3       Virginia       Wake         2014-06-29 03:00:00
 3       Virginia       GetDress     2014-06-29 04:00:00
            (Missing Event!)
 3       Virginia       Work         2014-06-29 04:30:00
```

Desired Result:

```
FirstNM   LastNM     EventLocation        WorkDate
-------   ------     -------------    -------------------
 Mary      West        Virginia       2014-06-30 07:00:00
 Derek     Smith       Virginia       2014-06-29 04:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @NameTBL TABLE
(   
    eID INT,
    FirstNM VARCHAR(50),
    LastNM VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @NameTBL
( eID, FirstNM, LastNM )
VALUES
(1     ,'John'        ,'Doe'),
(2     ,'Mary'        ,'West'),
(3     ,'Derek'       ,'Smith');


DECLARE @EventTBL TABLE
(
    eID INT,
    EventLocation VARCHAR(50),
    EventNM VARCHAR(50),
    EventDate DATETIME
)

DECLARE @EventType TABLE
( 
    EventName VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @EventType
( EventName )
VALUES
( 'Wake' ),
('GetDress'),
('DriveTo'),
('Work')

INSERT INTO @EventTBL
( eID, EventLocation, EventNM, EventDate )
VALUES
(1       ,'Virginia'       ,'Wake'         ,'2014-06-30 06:00:00'),
(1       ,'Virginia'       ,'GetDress'     ,'2014-06-30 06:30:00'),
(1       ,'Virginia'       ,'DriveTo'      ,'2014-06-30 06:45:00'),
(1       ,'Virginia'       ,'Work'         ,'2014-06-30 07:00:00'),
(2       ,'Virginia'       ,'Wake'         ,'2014-06-30 05:00:00'),
(2       ,'Virginia'       ,'GetDress'     ,'2014-06-30 06:00:00'),
(2       ,'Virginia'       ,'Work'         ,'2014-06-30 07:00:00'),
(3       ,'Virginia'       ,'Wake'         ,'2014-06-29 03:00:00'),
(3       ,'Virginia'       ,'GetDress'     ,'2014-06-29 04:00:00'),
(3       ,'Virginia'       ,'Work'         ,'2014-06-29 04:30:00');

SELECT m.* FROM
(
    SELECT n.eID, n.FirstNM, n.LastNM, e.EventName, t.EventDate, t.EventLocation
    FROM @NameTBL n
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.EventDate)) EventDate, 
                    t.EventLocation
        FROM @EventTBL t
        WHERE t.eID = n.eID
    ) t
    CROSS JOIN @EventType e
) m
LEFT JOIN @EventTBL d
    ON d.eID = m.eID
    AND d.EventNM = m.EventName
    AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, d.EventDate)) = m.EventDate
WHERE d.eID IS NULL
```

I added an eventtype table to find all the unique events (could have just queried the main table, but if all the records are missing an event, then you'd never know)
This outputs:

```
2   Mary    West    DriveTo 2014-06-30 00:00:00.000 Virginia
3   Derek   Smith   DriveTo 2014-06-29 00:00:00.000 Virginia
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it.  SQL Fiddle:

```
WITH cteEvents
AS
(
  SELECT 'Wake' AS Event
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GetDress' AS Event
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DriveTo' AS Event
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Work' AS Event
),
cteEventMatrix
AS
(
  SELECT    et.eID,
            et.EventLocation,
            e.Event,
            MAX(et.EventDate) AS EventDate
  FROM      EventTbl et, cteEvents e
  GROUP BY  et.eID,
            et.EventLocation,
            e.Event
)

SELECT    n.FirstNM,
          n.LastNM,
          em.EventLocation,
          em.EventDate
FROM      cteEventMatrix em INNER JOIN NameTbl n
          ON  em.eID = n.eID
WHERE     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EventTbl WHERE eID = em.eID AND EventNM = em.Event)
```

You want to create a matrix of all possible eIDs and events.  Then you want to query against EventTbl to see which of those do not exist.  We can use MAX of EventDate because it's DriveTo you're looking for, and so Work is the latest item of the day, and it exists.